# Invalid credentials (Failure) Gmail from Python without Less secure apps

Tags: python, google-apps-script, gmail

Google just disable the option to acces GMAIL disableing the option of work with Less secure Apps: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?authuser=3&hl=es-419&authuser=3&visit_id=637897778656476957-2028222503&p=less-secure-apps&rd=1

```
[ERROR] error: b'[AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 65, in lambda_handler
    imap4Obj = conectar_imap_correo(config_diccionario)
  File "/var/task/cargar_mensajes.py", line 31, in conectar_imap_correo
    imap4Obj.login(config_diccionario['credenciales']['default_email'],config_diccionario['credenciales']['password'])
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/imaplib.py", line 598, in login
    raise self.error(dat[-1])
```

Any idea to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deprecation of "less secure apps" means that apps that request username/password credentials will no longer work. Instead you have to use [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) to authenticate. You will have to learn how to implement it and apply the changes to your application's sign-in flow.

Aside from this there is no other workaround. This is just an evolution in security standards that Google has been announcing for [a while](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2019/12/less-secure-apps-oauth-google-username-password-incorrect.html). In their [documentation](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255) they say that Google Workspace accounts will keep LSAs for a while longer, but this is probably to allow more time for large enterprise companies to migrate away from legacy apps. Your only real long-term solution is to start using OAuth. I suggest you get started with Google's Python API [docs and samples](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/docs/README.md).