Why am I getting "invalid credentials" error using IMAP4 to access Gmail account?
I am attempting to create a program that can download attachments from gmail, but I am getting this error message:
Exception has occurred: IMAP4.error
b'[AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)'

Here is the relevant code snippet:
import imaplib
import email
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# accessing gmail inbox
user = "example@gmail.com"
password = "16-digit-code"
imap_url = 'imap.gmail.com'
my_mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_url)
my_mail.login(user, password)

I have 2-Factor Authentication and IMAP enabled. I also have a 16-digit app password which I read was needed since "less secure apps" is no longer an option, but none of this has seemed to do the trick.

This looks similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72479247/invalid-credentials-failure-gmail-from-python-without-less-secure-apps
